# Command prompt target into process.Start

Tags: c#

How do I convert my `command prompt` target into a `Process.Start` arguments?

**command code**

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\UiPath\Studio" && UiRobot.exe -file "C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Version 1\Main.xaml""
```

Comment: Syntax error, ',' expected.

Comment: `Process.Start("cmd", "/c \"cd \"C:\Program Files (x86)\UiPath\Studio\" && UiRobot.exe -file \"C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Version 1\Main.xaml\"\"");`